# How to fix Gutenberg with SiteOrigin page builder deleting content when editing

Tags: themes, block-editor

Our company has a custom built theme based on SiteOrigin's Pagebuilder. We've implemented a single-column site with 14 sections and scrollspy navigation. Since Gutenberg got pushed out the editing experience is fine for single posts, but on out main page any minor edits seem to result in large portions of the page getting deleted. The obvious solution to this is to use the classic editor, but it looks like WP is phasing that out and plans to hobble it over the near to short term. Any thoughts? I guess this should probably go in SiteOrigin's issue que, but I wanted to ask here first.

Comment: There's no plans to "hobble" the classic editor. It will be preserved as-is until at least the end of 2021. Anyway, you're right, this sounds like a SiteOrigin issue. I would contact them for support. 3rd-party themes and plugins are off-topic here.

Comment: Perhaps I used a little hyperbole, but from what I've read the plan is to phase the classic edit out overtime.

Comment: There's no phase out. The classic editor is being replaced immediately in 5.0 (for Pages and Posts). The classic editor can be restored with the Classic Editor plugin, and this plugin will be officially supported until December 31, 2021. You can read the announcement about this [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/11/07/classic-editor-plugin-support-window/).

Comment: Cheers, there's clearly misunderstanding in the ecosystem